# TypeError: Error #2007 - Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, flash-cs6

When I'm testing the movie this appears:

TypeError: Error #2007: El valor del parámetro hitTestObject debe ser distinto de null.

```
at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
at DragDrop/drop()
```

Here's the DragDrop Code:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;


    public class DragDrop extends Sprite
    {
        var origX:Number;
        var origY:Number;
        var target:DisplayObject;

        public function DragDrop()
        {
            origX = x;
            origY = y;

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
            buttonMode = true;

        }

        function drag(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
            startDrag();
            parent.addChild(this);
        }

        function drop(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
            stopDrag();

            if(hitTestObject(target))
            {
                visible = false;
                target.alpha = 50;
                Object(parent).match();
            }

            x = origX;
            y = origY;

        }

    }

}
```

Please I need your help.

Here the all asstes that you may need.
http://www.mediafire.com/?t1b1u2ipbpj1a8t

Comment: Where do you assign `target`? You object does not know about its `target` until you give it that target. And no, it won't look up target in another class's variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `target` Object is never being set! You need to define target!

Comment: And how do I degine it? Please help me